What is the "Gödel ordering of algorithms"?
I was reading this paper, and in example 3.8 appeared the idea of "Gödel ordering of algorithm". Does anyone know what is this ordering? I've seen some things about Gödel ordering, but nothing to do with algorithms and that example appear to not work with any "random" enumeration, I think.

See godel numbers and encoding

From the paper you linked: "In any programming language there is only a countable number of possible algorithms. Fixing the language, we can enumerate them all (for instance, lexicographically). Given such an ordered list $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of all algorithms, the index $n$ is usually called the Godel number of the algorithm $A_n$."

The exact numbering scheme is generally not important. You could imagine reading the binary version of your .py or .exe file, adding a 1 in front so that leading 0s aren't an issue, and interpreting it as a number in binary.

The numbering isn't totally irrelevant, you do have to map operations (for example algorithmic composition) to expressions in the arithmetic language.  But it is mostly irrelevant.

Generically, the idea of Gödel numbering was to encode statements about an axiomatic system in the language of the system so as to enable a univocal self-reference within the system.
Specifically, it is a map of statements about the system of natural numbers (i.e., Peano Arithmetic) onto a unique natural number called Gödel number, thus, arithmetising the discourse on PA.
Some authors of computational theory use the term for any arithmetisation of the elements of a formal language so that they can be processed by an appropriate algorithm (as in the cited paper). Thus, in their usage, "Gödel ordering" is nothing but an ordering done with respect to the numbers assined in Gödel's style.
Nevertheless, this usage is clearly bereft of Gödel's innovative idea and an instance of misguided terminology.
